# Need inputs to access value from baseURI

Tags: protractor

I need to fetch text from baseURI value. Here is the HTML DOM.

- HTMLCollection [input.hidden-input]

  - 0: input.hidden-input

    - accept: "" accessKey: "" align: "" alt: "" assignedSlot: null attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 0} attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: class, 1: readonly, class: class, readonly: readonly, length: 2} autocapitalize: "" autocomplete: "" autofocus: false baseURI: "https://google.com/files_0.0.76_a95b9c0_190204_211505/" checked: false childElementCount: 0 childNodes: NodeList [] children: HTMLCollection [] classList: DOMTokenList ["hidden-input", value: "hidden-input"] className: "hidden-input" clientHeight: 22 clientLeft: 2 clientTop: 2 clientWidth: 149 contentEditable: "inherit" dataset: DOMStringMap {} defaultChecked: false defaultValue: "" dir: "" dirName: "" disabled: false draggable: false files: null firstChild: null firstElementChild: null form: null

Any suggestions on how to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inspect and find the unqiue locator for the element that contains the BaseURl.

Then do as below in you `it()` block.

For Example, Let `ele = element(by.id('value'));`

Now get the baseUrl,

`ele.getAttribute('baseURI');`

So the above line returns you the attribute value.

Hope it helps you